# Assumption on characteristics in an exercise about roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I'm solving the following exercise: "Let $K$ be a field, $char(K) \nmid 2n$ for $n \geq 1$ an *odd* integer. If $K$ contains a primitive $n$-th root of unity, then it also contains a primitive $2n$-th root of unity."

My solution looks like this: Let $\xi$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity in $K$. I claim that $- \xi$ is a $2n$-th root of unity. By assumption for all $k \in \{ 1, ..., n-1 \}$, we have $\xi^k \neq 1$. Hence $(- \xi)^k \neq -1$, because otherwise $(- \xi)^{2k} = 1$ and also $n \mid 2k$, - which is impossible, as $n$ is odd and $k < n$.

Therefore $(- \xi)^{n + k} = (- \xi)^n (- \xi)^k = (-1) \cdot (- \xi)^k \neq 1$.

For $k \in \{1, ..., n \}$: If $(- \xi)^k = (-1)^k \xi^k = 1$, we get an immediate contradiction for $k$ being even, and for $k \neq n$ odd also, namely $\xi^k = -1 \Rightarrow \xi^{2k} = 1$, leading again to a contradiction as $n \mid 2k$, but $n$ is odd and $k \leq n$.

So for all $l \in \{ 1, ..., 2n - 1 \}$, we have $(- \xi)^{l} \neq 1$, which had to be proved.

What confuses me now: I don't see why one would use the assertion on the characteristics. Is my proof wrong or is it a special case, which I did not see?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here is a problem you did not discuss in your solution if $\xi=-\xi$ I mean $\text{char}(K)=2$ then $\xi$ is both a $n$th root of unity and a $2n$ th root of unity clearly impossible

Comment: You have only proven $\left(-\xi\right)^l\neq 1$ for $n+1 \leq l < 2n$. You need to do it in the case $1 \leq l \leq n$ as well. Here you will need $\operatorname{char} K \neq 2$. The rest of the assumption, as Elaqqad says, is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Completely forgot to write primitive...

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the statement and your proof is correct, the only restriction is :
$$\text{char}\  K\neq 2 $$

So that $1 \neq -1$ are distinct elements